# Get access to the context of InheritedWidget

Tags: dart, flutter, inherited-widget

I am having the following setup:

```
MaterialApp(home:SplashScreen)


SplashScreen(
///do some auth checks then
Navigator.of(context).push( MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) =>  StateInheritedWidget(
                  user: userData,
                  child:  HomePage(),

                )))
)
```

Then in my `HomePage` I have a FAB that pushes a new route. This new route has no access to the context of my inherited widget.

Is it impossible to get the context of an `InheritedWidget` in new routes, or is there a way to solve this issue ?

---

**Update**

This is my MaterialApp's builder property

```
    builder: (context,child){
///Doing some auth stuff here
        return new StateInheritedWidget(
          user: userData,
                      child: userData==null?const SplashScreen(child: const LoginPage(),): 
                      const SplashScreen(child: const HomePage(),),

        );
      },
```

My `SplashScreen` build method:

```
return !_load? new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text('Splash'),
      ),
    ):this.widget.child;
```

These are the error I get.

The first one seems to be related to the `Drawer` in my `HomePage`:

```
I/flutter (12688): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (12688): The following assertion was thrown building Tooltip("Open navigation menu", vertical offset: 24.0,
I/flutter (12688): position: below, dirty, state: _TooltipState#44ae9(ticker inactive)):
I/flutter (12688): No Overlay widget found.
I/flutter (12688): Tooltip widgets require an Overlay widget ancestor for correct operation.
I/flutter (12688): The most common way to add an Overlay to an application is to include a MaterialApp or Navigator
I/flutter (12688): widget in the runApp() call.
I/flutter (12688): The specific widget that failed to find an overlay was:
I/flutter (12688):   Tooltip("Open navigation menu", vertical offset: 24.0, position: below)
I/flutter (12688):
```

The second exception appears when I click on FAB (Navigator.push)

```
I/flutter (12688): Another exception was thrown: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. That's not possible (or at least not recommended).

The problem lies in the fact that your inheritedWidget shouldn't be *inside* the route but instead *above* the route. Usually above `MaterialApp`

> But I want my Authentification to be able to push a login screen, I can't put it above `MaterialApp` !

Which is why I said `usually`. :D

Authentification is one of these exceptions. You may want your authent layer to access the Navigator. But still want to share that authent layer with *all* routes.

This is where an useful property of `MaterialApp` is used : [`builder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp/builder.html)

Builder, when passed, will be used to insert any kind of widget right above your routes. But still be after `Navigator` so that you can still push new routes when needed.

In the end, you'd have

```
new MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return new MyAuthent(child: child);
  },
  ...
  // home: SplashSceen ?
);
```

This will most likely requires a refactor on your end. But that's the proper way to achieve this.

Comment: Is MyAuthent in your example the inherited widget ? and does this mean I do not need the home property of MaterialApp , I can just return the splash widget instead as MyAuthent child ?

Comment: Can you clarify this please, I am not sure what I am doing is the right thing, I am getting this error:
`E/flutter (11514): Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
E/flutter (11514): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.`

Comment: I have updated the question to show you my changes and the exact errors I am getting

Comment: That's not what I told you to do duh !  `builder` should only wrap `child`. Not override it. Or you'll break the whole `Navigator` thing. But yeah, MyAuthent is an inherited widget. Or a stateful widget that instantiate an InheritedWidget.

Comment: Your builder never use `child` property. `child` is your actual view.

Comment: Ops, ye I see. but where do I get this child from ? Can you mirror my use case to your example please ?

Comment: It's passed as parameter to `builder`. That's the current pushed route (or home by default).

Comment: I still do not understand how it can be integrated in my example.