# Flutter: Inherited Widget and Routes

Tags: dart, flutter, inherited-widget

I want to have an inherited widget at the root of my application, which will contain my data providers, which I would use throughout the app. So I have this inherited widget, but every time I try to load it I get this `The getter 'data' was called on null` and I can't figure out why.

So here's my main.dart:

```
void main() => runApp(new MatAppRoot());

class MatAppRoot extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyCoolApp',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        'Login': (BuildContext context) => new LoginPage(),
        'Cool': (BuildContext context) => new CoolPage(),
      },
      home: new CoolApp(),
    );
  }
}

class CoolAppextends StatefulWidget {

  final Widget child;

  CoolApp({this.child});

  @override
  CoolAppState createState() => new CoolAppState();

  static CoolAppState of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(CoolInherit) as CoolInherit).data;
  }
}

class CoolAppState extends State<CoolApp> {
  String randomString = 'AYEEAS!!!';

  @override
  void initState() { super.initState();
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('Login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new CoolInherit(
      data: this,
      child: new LoginPage(),
    );
  }

}

class CoolInherit extends InheritedWidget {

  final CoolAppState data;

  CoolInherit({
    Key key,
    this.data,
    Widget child,
  }): super(
    key: key,
    child: child
  );

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(CoolInherit old) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

then my `LoginPage` basically redirects after the login like this:

```
if (logInSuccessful) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('Cool', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
}
```

In my `Cool` page I try to load another page when clicking a button like this:

```
viewCoolDetails() {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new CoolDetailsPage()),
  );
}
```

but in my `CoolDetailsPage` it crashes when I do this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final inheritedWidget = CoolApp.of(context);
  print(inheritedWidget.randomString);   <-- ERROR: The getter 'data' was called on null
  return new Text('Cool!');
}
```

Error Details:

```
I/flutter ( 6129): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6129): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building CoolDetailsPage(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 6129): _CoolDetailsPage#ba0bb):
I/flutter ( 6129): The getter 'data' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 6129): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 6129): Tried calling: data
I/flutter ( 6129):
I/flutter ( 6129): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 6129): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:46:5)
I/flutter ( 6129): #1      CoolApp.of (/lib/main.dart:56:83)
... etc etc
```

main.dart:56 is `return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(CoolInherit) as CoolInherit).data;` and so if my detective work is up to par, I suspect it is something to with navigations/context, which is preventing my final widget from accessing the inheritedWidget, but I'm not sure about that.

UPDATE:

the best I can tell, I need to insert my InheritedWidget at a higher level; before the navigator. so I inserted this into the MaterialApp:

```
builder: (context, child) {
  return new CoolApp(child: child);
},
```

but that didn't seen to work...

```
E/flutter (32321): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (32321): Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
E/flutter (32321): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.
E/flutter (32321): #0      Navigator.of.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1180:9)
E/flutter (32321): #1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1187:6)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem for a long time and I realized that if you wrap the MaterialApp with the Inherited Widget, your **data is accessible through the entire app.** But in your case, you need to pass data after the user login so to do that you need to **create a new Navigator and wrap it with your Inherited Widget.** You can see this project https://github.com/johnstef99/inherited-widget-demo

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'InheritedWidget Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyNav(),
    );
  }
}

Route generatePage(child) {
  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => child);
}

class MyNav extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyData(
      data: 'omg',
      child: Navigator(
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          switch (settings.name) {
            case 'page1':
              return generatePage(PageOne());
            case 'page2':
              return generatePage(PageTwo());
            case 'page3':
              return generatePage(PageThree());
          }
        },
        initialRoute: 'page1',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyData extends InheritedWidget {
  MyData({Key key, this.child, this.data}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final Widget child;
  final String data;

  static MyData of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(MyData) as MyData);
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(MyData oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 1'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Goto page 2, data=${MyData.of(context).data}"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PageTwo()));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 2'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Goto page 3, data=${MyData.of(context).data}"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PageThree()));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageThree extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 3'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Goto page 4, data=${MyData.of(context).data}"),
        onPressed: null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right. However in my case did't work if you want to get route arguments with `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments`. It returns `null`

Answer (score 2):

That is because you're trying to access `CoolApp` which is in the route `/` from another route (dynamic).

But inside your dynamic route, there's no `CoolApp`. So `CoolApp.of(context)` returns null, and therefore accessing `.data` crashes.

You need to find a way to have a `CoolApp` instance inside your new route.

For more informations, take a look at [Get access to the context of InheritedWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328362/get-access-to-the-context-of-inheritedwidget/49329255#49329255)

Comment: That makes sense... That's the part I've been stuck on. Not sure how to get that into the new Route. I see in the other question you're referencing they talk about the `MaterialApp builder` but not sure how I would implement that, or if it's what I need, in this scenario.

Comment: Still confused about this... Can't seem to find anything online about how I might do something like this in a way that works...

Comment: I added `builder: (context, child) { return new CoolApp(child: child);},` to the MaterialApp, because from what I can tell that will inject the state before the navigator... but that didn't seem to help... :(

Comment: Found a good way of doing this here: `http://ericwindmill.com/using-flutter-inherited-widgets-effectively`

Comment: @Jus10 did you find the solution?